# Spark: Custom operator for JavaPairRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to declare a custom operator for JavaPairRDD, here is the code:

```
object CustomOperators {

  implicit class CustomRDDOperator[K: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](rdd: JavaPairRDD[K, V]) {
    def customOp = {
      // logic
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm not able to call this function from my JavaPairRDD.

I'm very new to Scala, so there is a good chance that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Need some guidance.

What would be the best way to add a custom function to JavaPairRDD?

Answer (score 2):

You should just need to add `import CustomOperators._` in the file where you are using it. But if you are working from Scala, you shouldn't end up with a `JavaPairRDD` in the first place (unless you are using third-party library intended to be used primarily from Java).

Comment: I'm using Spark's java api. I can change the project to use scala as well, but changing the complete Spark job to use Scala is not possible,

Comment: You can't use an "extension method" like this from Java. Well, you can, but it would look like `CustomOperators.CustomRDDOperator(rdd, ClassTag.apply(K.class), ...).customOp` if not worse. For use from Java, just write a normal static method instead (and if you can't avoid `ClassTag`, pass a `Class` instead).

Comment: Do you mean extend JavaPairRDD and then add custom Operator?